# Run a simple test in Mocha

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocha.js

I'm trying to do a simple test in Mocha to verify that the result of a division return a number but the test is always pending.

```
describe("Return result", () => {
   it("return a nb when string.lgth / number"), () => {
    const text = "oula";
    assert.equal((text.length/2),2)
   }
```

})

What did i do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is a minimal error but still an error.

The definition is bad written, should be

`it("...", () => {`

But you have:

`it("..."), () => {`

Is almost the same, but hang the execution.

By the way, I recommend use `assert.StrictEqual()` because `assert.equal()` is deprecated.

So the working code:

```
describe("Return result", () => {
    it("return a nb when string.lgth / number", () => {
        const text = "oula";
        assert.strictEqual((text.length/2),2)
    })
})
```